# Filtering out dataframes from a dictonary, that fufill a condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dictionary which holds dataframes, called `mini_dfs`

I'm looping through the keys and values of the dictonary, where each value represents a dataframe. Each dataframe has a column called `log_return`

Here is a sample dataframe

```
            Open  High   Low  Close      Volume  log_return   
Date                                                                      
2016-06-21  9.97  9.99  9.54   9.70  11370687.0    0.054010       - 
2016-06-22  9.67  9.67  9.30   9.36   4973859.0   -0.035681          
2016-06-23  9.52  9.75  9.46   9.75   3149880.0    0.040822
```

`

I want to filter out the dataframes, whose log_return column sum is greater than 0.
The below code outputs boolean values

```
for keys, values in mini_dfs.items():
       values.log_return.sum() >0
```

`False
True
True
True
False
False
True
True
False
False
False
True
False
False
False`

However, I'm not exactly sure how to elegantly use boolean filtering, to display only the dataframes that fufill my condition.

I tried

```
for keys, values in mini_dfs.items():
    values.loc[values.log_return.sum() >0]
```

which resulted in `keyError: 'the label [False] is not in the [index]'`
as well as

```
for keys, values in mini_dfs.items():
    values[values.log_return.sum() >0]
```

which resulted in

`KeyError: False`

Comment: Is there a reason you need to loop through them? Why not typical boolean indexing?

Comment: I don't need to loop through them but I wasn't really sure how to use typical boolean indexing with a dictionary of dataframes.  Maybe my brain is just fried I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on the structure of your dataframes. Are they single rows? Either way, I've created a very simple dictionary of dataframes to replicate this. I am storing the dataframes as keys. Try a variation of the following:

```
for i in mini_dfs.values():
    print(i[i['log_return'] > 0])
```

This structure should return each of the dataframe rows with the desired condition.

As a follow up:

It looks like you're almost there. You could throw an "if" line in there checking if the sum is greater than zero. Does this work?

```
for i in mini_dfs.values():
    if i['log_return'].sum() > 0:
        i
```

This will return the whole dataframe that fits the sum condition. Does this work for you?

Comment: I've included a sample of how my dataframe looks in the OP. 
I have a dictionary of dataframes, so each key represents a dataframe (value).
The code you have written, doesn't include the sum portion of the code`['log_return].sum() >0]'. I'm trying to filter out only the dataframes (values) whose column `['log_return']` 's sum() is great than 0. Hopefully that makes things more clear.   Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Your updated version works but I was told it's bad practice to use `if``loops when using pandas and numpy because it's much slower than booleaning indexing.  I will wait a bit and see if anyone has an answer that utilizes the pandas/numpy boolean indexing, but if not I will give you the credit for the correct answer. Thank you so much for your help =)

Comment: I don't know your data but I would think creating a multi-index dataframe (your dictionary values would be a level in the index) would perform much better than storing multiple dataframes in a dictionary. You should consider this approach and perform the indexing on the corresponding dictionary value level.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into multi-index dataframes.